# How to hide clipPath in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg, clip-path

I want to hide the clipPath element so it doesn't show empty white space in the browser, but I still want to be able to use it from other svgs, like the image.

If I put width 0 and height 0 on it then IE won't show the image either.

If I put display:none the image doesn't show up in any browser.

```html
<svg height="0" width="0" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath">
      <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="200" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <image xlink:href="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1530/25831337243_d27d32ceb5_z_d.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" clip-path="url(#svgPath)" />
</svg>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Put it in the same svg as the `<image>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in the same SVG as the image and there's nothing to hide.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath">
      <circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="200" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1530/25831337243_d27d32ceb5_z_d.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" clip-path="url(#svgPath)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: but I have many image svgs on the page and I don't want to duplicate the id and code for the clippath every time.

Comment: Why would you need to duplicate everything. Just pick one SVG, put it in there and use it in the rest.